# how to change default page url in team site in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i need to change all the sub-site default page url to my custom layout page url.

for ex: i have a one sub site call : http://test:1210/Site1/default.aspx. using coding i want to set this to : http://test:1210/Site1/_layouts/pages/test1.aspx.

is it possible in team site to change default page url using coding.

Answer (score 2):

Team site default pages are default.aspx, so you have to do something like this:

http://attis.org/blogs/dan/archive/2008/10/29/how-to-change-the-default-page-of-a-sharepoint-site-using-a-feature.aspx

If you were using the publishing feature, you could set the welcome page

https://serverfault.com/questions/183943/change-sharepoint-team-site-home-page

Comment: thanks for reply. for your links i need to create a custom page . which i dont want. i have to used this code: SPFolder rootFolder = webItem.RootFolder;
rootFolder.WelcomePage = "login.aspx";
rootFolder.Update();  . This work fine at root web. but does not work in sub site level. dont know what i am did wrong. please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to set the default page in a Team Site from code behind :

SPFolder rootFolder = Web.RootFolder; // root folder of the web object

rootFolder.WelcomePage = "SitePages/xyz.aspx"; // url of the page you want to set as default page

rootFolder.Update();